# Which are the advantages of parametric modeling over implicit modeling?

Tags: parametric, implicit-function

I hope that this is the correct site to ask this question, but since I was unable to find one specifically for modeling, I decided to ask here (and please feel free to correct me, if any of my statements is bogus):

There are tools which allow one to do parametric modeling like [Rhino's Grasshopper](https://www.rhino3d.com/6/new/grasshopper/) or [Blender's Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html). The modeling happens in a bottom-up manner, e.g., twisting and bending some input shape according to some parametric functions.

And then there are implicit modeling tools like [nTop](https://www.ntop.com/) (formerly "nTopology") which allow modeling with implicit functions, and therefore enable a top-down workflow, e.g., you have some shape and describe with combinations of implicit functions that is shall have rounded corners and be filled with a fancy pattern.

But the implicit modeling tools are, I think, relatively new on the market and generally only smaller and light-weight tools. I specifically wonder about the reasons for that.

And my question would be: Is there something that can easily be done with parametric modeling which is hard to be done with implicit modeling? And if so, what and why?